# Split a row into several, with an identifier

Tags: excel

I have a large spreadsheet with a set of data I wish to split out into several rows.

The format is as follows:

ID A B C D

These are in separate columns, and I want them to display in the format of

ID A
ID B
ID C
ID D
ID2 A
ID2 B
ID2 C
ID2 D

And so on.  I'm not really sure how I could do this - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find both a VBA, and a formula based solution in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/633124/how-do-i-split-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-excel) on superuser, with detailed explanations.

VBA code tailored to your situation:

```
Sub NewLayout()
    ' go over the rows
    outrow = 0
    For rowi = 1 To Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        ' go over columns B..E
        For coli = 2 To 5
            ' for every cell: move down a row, copy id, cell value
            outrow = outrow + 1
            Cells(rowi, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(outrow, 10)
            Cells(rowi, coli).Copy Destination:=Cells(outrow, 11)
        Next coli
    Next rowi
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula solution:

[image: The picture is shown here.]

Cell `H1` is the delimiter. In this case a space.

```
Helper:=SUM(C1,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,$H$1,"")))+1
```

You must fill the formula one row more.

```
E1:=a1

E2:=LOOKUP(ROW(1:1),$C:$C,A:A)&""

F1:=b1

F2:=MID($H$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$C:$C,B:B)&$H$1,FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($H$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$C:$C,B:B)&$H$1,$H$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$C:$C)))+1,FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($H$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$C:$C,B:B)&$H$1,$H$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$C:$C)+1))-FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($H$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$C:$C,B:B)&$H$1,$H$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$C:$C)))-1)&""
```

Cons:

Numbers will be converted to Text.
Of course you can remove the `&""` at the end of the formula, but blank cells will be filled with 0.